# How to specify where to place buildout bootstrap generated folders?

Tags: python, buildout

I have the following folder structure:

```
bootstrap.py
setup.py
conf/
    buildout.cfg
```

Now how do I make it so that running `python bootstrap.py` puts the generated folders bin, eggs, parts, etc. on the root instead of under conf folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base directory for buildout is always the directory that the starting configuration file is found in, so in your case that's in `conf/`.

There are two work-arounds for this, one easy, one harder. The first is to just place a bare `buildout.cfg` file in the root, and have it include the file in `conf/`:

```
[buildout]
extends = conf/buildout.cfg
```

Alternatively, you can set the `*-directory` options in your `conf/buildout.cfg` file for each of the `eggs`, `develop-eggs`, `parts` and `bin` directories:

```
[buildout]
bin-directory = ../bin
parts-directory = ../parts
eggs-directory = ../eggs
develop-eggs-directory = ../develop-eggs
```

That'll set the these directories to the parent of your `conf/` directory; e.g. the same directory your bootstrap file is in.

However, any recipe that still refers to `${buildout:directory}` will still use the `conf/` directory insead of your project root dir. You cannot set that option to a relative path, you must either let buildout set it for you or specify a full path:

```
[buildout]
directory = /full/path/to/directory
```

In my opinion, you are best off using the first option, it makes running the bootstrap script easier anyway as it by default looks for a `buildout.cfg` file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `buildout.cfg` in your root, which extends your buildout in conf directory:

```
[buildout]
extends=conf/buildout.cfg
```

I usually have few buildout config files for example: `base`, `developer`, `deployment` under directory `buildout`, so I use this method myself to bootstrap the file I need.

Comment: You cannot use quotes; they are part of the filename now, and there is no `"conf` directory with a `buildout.cfg"` file in it. :-P

Comment: Thanks :) I always forget that.